# how to change value of a cell in kendoGrid from a child window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I want to change value of a cell in kendoGrid from a child window this is my parent window code (consider that I have kendoGrid in it):

```
 function onDataBound(e) {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");

        $("#d_roz").on("keypress", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                {

                    grid.addRow();

                }

            }
        });


        $(grid.tbody).on("keydown", "td", function (ev) {
            if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
               var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
                var colIdx = $("td", row).index(this);

                //var data = grid.dataItem(grid.tbody.find('tr:eq(' + colIdx + ')'));
                // console.log(data.cod1);

                var cod1 = e.sender._data[rowIdx].cod1;
                var sh_cod1 = e.sender._data[rowIdx].sh_cod1;

                if (colIdx == 0 && is_open_find == false) {




                    cellSender = e.sender._data[rowIdx]; //this is a global variable I use 


                    childWindow = window.open(testu, "_blank", null, false);
}});});
```

and in my child window I have following code :

```
 id = ui.item.id; //this is the value I wanted from child window

                window.opener.isPosted = true;


               window.opener.cellSender.cod1 = id; // and I will change the value of cell here


                self.close();
```

The problem is cell value will changed but kendo doesn't  show the change until I re-focus on the grid which I don't want to do that.

What Should I do for that?

Comment: You will need to get the selected dataItem of the Grid and then update the value in that dataItem object rather than cell.

Comment: if you write your comment as answer I will check it for correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the selected dataItem of the Grid and then update the value in that dataItem object rather than cell.